# Determine zoom level that contains all polylines in Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, polyline

I am visualizing movements on a map and want to set the zoom level dependent on the span of the polylines which visualize the movement. I already found an answer how to do this for [markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173010/mapbox-android-determine-zoom-level-that-contain-all-markers), but I can't figure out how to get the span of the visualized data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use the solution mentioned above by including all movements to the `LatLngBounds`. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
Builder latLngBoundsBuilder = new Builder();
for (int i = 0; i < movements.size(); i++) {
  latLngBoundsBuilder.include(movements.get(i).getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = latLngBoundsBuilder.build();
```